# Why did the Ferengi DaiMon distort his image on the view screen?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode "The Last Outpost", Data remarks that the Ferengi distorted his image. Was it ever revealed the reason why he did so?

Comment: He is insecure? He learned the trick of distorting his image from Balok? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Corbomite_Maneuver

Answer (score 7):

To make himself look "large and menacing", according to the [original screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/107.txt)

> [The MAIN VIEWER FLICKERS and AN IMAGE OF DAIMON TAAR'S
>       FERENGI FACE comes into sight -- large, menacing,
>       lens-twisted and very brightly lit.]

Later we actually meet the Ferengi

> [Sitting opposite Riker on a crystalline rock is a little
>       Ferengi humanoid, LETEK, leader of this group. His eyes
>       "dart" around birdlike as he studies the Starfleet
>       insignia just taken from Riker. **He is fine-boned, small
>       -- looking far different and less menacing than the
>       image transmitted to the Enterprise Main Viewer.]**